# Calculate cumulative sum from last non-zero values for each column of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe below. For each column, I have many zeros with some non-zero values. I would like to calculate cumulative sum for each column, but I want the cumsum to be reset when a zero value occurs.

My original dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1],'b':[1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]})

   a  b
0  1  1
1  0  0
2  1  0
3  0  0
4  1  0
5  0  1
6  1  1
7  1  1
```

i would like to have a cumulative sum like this:

```
   a  b
0  1  1
1  0  0
2  1  0
3  0  0
4  1  0
5  0  1
6  1  2
7  2  3
```

Is is possible to do it without loop in python? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way would be creating custom groupers for each column checking for element-wise equality with `0` and taking the [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) of the resulting series of booleans, and transforming with the `cumsum`:

```
g = df.eq(0).cumsum()
df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(g[x.name]).transform('cumsum'))

   a  b
0  1  1
1  0  0
2  1  0
3  0  0
4  1  0
5  0  1
6  1  2
7  2  3
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot completely avoid looping, 
but you can avoid formal looping notaions.

`sum(x-1000 if x > 1000 else x for x in x_sph_rand)` will do it with a generator, which is a bit better, but still uses a loop...